# React Native Navigation - createBottomTabNavigator and hiding Tab Bar

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am working with an Expo app which comes bundles with the react-native-navigation.

It works great and I have setup several Stacked Navigations but I cannot seem to get my modals to display without the bottom Tab Navigator.

Below is the navigation folder structure:

[image]

Here are the files:

AppNavigator.js

```
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator'

export default createSwitchNavigator({
  Main: MainTabNavigator
})
```

MainTabNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

// Import Stacks
import SettingsStack from './stacks/SettingsStack.js'

// Import Components
import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon'

// Import Screens
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen'
import ExercisesScreen from '../screens/ExercisesScreen'
import ExerciseDetailScreen from '../screens/ExerciseDetailScreen'
import VideoScreen from '../screens/VideoScreen'
import ExerciseStartScreen from '../screens/ExerciseStartScreen'

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  ExerciseDetails: ExerciseDetailScreen
})

const StartWorkOut = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  ExerciseStart: ExerciseStartScreen
})

StartWorkOut.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarVisible: false
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Main: HomeStack,
  ExerciseStart: ExerciseStartScreen,
  VideoScreen: {
    screen: VideoScreen
  }
},
{
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
  tabBarVisible: false
})

const ExercisesStack = createStackNavigator({
  Exercises: ExercisesScreen,
  ExerciseDetails: ExerciseDetailScreen
})

const ExerciseRootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Main: ExercisesStack,
  VideoScreen: {
    screen: VideoScreen
  }
},
{
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
  tabBarVisible: false
})

RootStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  )
}

ExerciseRootStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Exercises',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  )
}

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  RootStack,
  ExerciseRootStack,
  SettingsStack
})
```

The settings Stack file is not important and I have tried adding the following into screens, without any luck:

```
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarVisible: false
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out in the end.

I had to refactor the code and remove the modals from the tab navigator and add it directly to the AppNAvigator.js as below:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator'

// Import Screens
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen.js'
import ExerciseStartScreen from '../screens/ExerciseStartScreen.js'
import VideoScreen from '../screens/VideoScreen.js'

export default createStackNavigator({
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
  ExerciseStart: ExerciseStartScreen,
  VideoScreen: VideoScreen
},
{
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null
  }
})
```